# How to allow [Authorize] inside a custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom AuthorizeAttribute like this

```
public class DevMode : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (myConditionToAuthorize)
        {
            // how to allow [Authorize] ?
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is used along with [Authorize] tag like this:

```
[Authorize, DevMode]
public class UserController : ApiController { ... }
```

I need to allow `[Authorize] == true` inside `[DevMode]`

Or it is better to put them all together inside a unique authorize class? But then I dont know tho to check Authorize data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Or it is better to put them all together inside a unique authorize class?

Oh yes, that would indeed be better. You could simply derive from the `AuthorizeAttribute` and call the base method:

```
public class DevModeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var authorize = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // the user is not authorized, no need to go any further
            return false;
        }

        // now apply your custom authorization logic here and return true or false
        ...
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[DevMode]
public class UserController : ApiController { ... }
```

Comment: There is no `IsAuthorized` method in `AuthorizeAttribute` and `AuthorizeAttribute` is not called in `ApiController`.. only `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` is. (i'm using framework 4.5). Take a closer look an my sample.

Comment: `There is no IsAuthorized method in AuthorizeAttribute`: are you sure about that, take a closer look at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute.isauthorized(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: There's a huge difference between `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` and `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`. I hope you are using the latter as the first is obviously not called in an API controller. Also if you are using ASP.NET Web API why is your question tagger with `asp.net-mvc` instead of being tagged with `asp.net-web-api`? I will update it to fix this misunderstanding between the 2 technologies that might confuse the readers.

Comment: Hah! @darin, yes i messed everything! sorry :) I'm noob yet.

Comment: Is there anyway to access the IPrincipal User object within this class - say if you placed it in Global.asax.cs?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to add a custom IsAdmin (based on claims) using this method

```
public class IsAdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        IPrincipal principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
        return principal.IsAdmin();
    }
}
```

it kind of answers my own last comment so hope it helps someone else please note the .IsAdmin is an extension method on the IPrincipal that checks claims.